# Tree View which uses up to N levels only

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have this tree structure which I want to display in 2 tree views. Both tree view will use the same collection.

- Eastern Conference

  - Atlantic

    - New York

      - Melo
    - Brooklyn

      - Deron
    - Boston

      - Rondo
  - Central

    - Chicago
    - Indiana
  - Southwest

    - Miami
    - Atlanta

Now for the first tree view, I would just like to display the conference and division only and for the second tree view, conference, division and city and NOT the star players.

Now, I have already achieved my desired result for the first tree view using the xaml below:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Conference}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Division}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="3"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Now I am stuck on how to ignore the star players and just display the conference, division and city for the second tree view.

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Conferences}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Divisions}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Remember to set the datacontext for the window/usercontrol where the treeview lives.